# How to start Bootstrap animation after preloader is finished?

Tags: html, css, animation, preload

I'm using some css animations on the startup of my website, but I want them to only start after the preloader. When I load the page, the preloader takes a few seconds to complete and the animations don't play because they were already played on load which could not be seen because the preloader was being shown.

So after the suggestions, this is what it looks like:

```
<head>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#logg").addClass("animated rollIn");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="preloader">
<div id="status"> <img src="assets/img/preloader.gif" height="64" width="64" alt=""> </div>
</div>
<div class="coming-soon">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
     <div class="logo">
    <img id="logg" src="assets/img/logo6.png" alt="logo" style="max-width: 260px; height:auto; display:inline-block;">
</div>
```

The code above doesn't play the animation, and I downloaded the animation from [here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe it has to do with inline style ? it overrides css written in file or loaded in between style tags ...

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks for the reply! I tried to remove the inline style but the animation still does not load. It loads find when I use `class="animated rollIn"` but not with the script. Any other ideas?

Comment: did you not forgot to load jquery ?

Comment: @GCyrillus sorry, how will I check that? Thanks!

Comment: Just a little tip, the javascript error could have been spotted by yourself if you were familiar with [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (I supposed you use Chrome right?). It's a invaluable tool for web developers, make use of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `load` event instead. The `load` event is fired when **all resources** are ready. In other hand, `ready` is fired when the DOM structure is ready and generally that's the first thing that is loaded.

Also make sure that all your resources are inside your `<head>` element and you `<img>` is either an `inline-block` or `block` element.

All that I've said is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#logg").addClass("animated rollIn");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img id="logg" src="assets/img/logo6.png" alt="logo" style="max-width: 260px; height:auto; display:inline-block;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### EDIT

Now that the OP provided the link for the page was quite easy to spot the error.
You're trying to use jQuery's `$` alias **before** including jQuery itself. The order matters, so put all those jQuery scripts that are the bottom of the source code in the beginning of your `<head>` tag :)

```
// Put those at the top of your <head>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried this but there is no animation, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @coloroid in this case it's something to do with your animation. I'm doing some research on this. But anyway the load event still the right one, okay?! hang on

Comment: When I use `class= "animated rollIn"` the animation loads fine, but when I use the script, it does not work. Is there something I need to fix?

Comment: @coloroid give a try now. Can you provide which library are you using for animations? Bootstrap doesn't include these kind of animations AFAIK.

Comment: I just tried that but the animation still doesn't seem to play. I downloaded an animation css from here:

[link](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: @coloroid now we are talking :) That link should be in your question as well. Hang on and I'll check what you did wrong...

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch! (:

Comment: @coloroid It seems that you've done everything right, but maybe you didn't loaded the css library properly. Double check if don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: @coloroid I believe I've found what's wrong. Check my updated answer and make sure your image has the `display` set to `inline-block`;

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. The animation still isn't playing. I relinked the css file, placed the `<script>` code inside the `<head>` and added `display:inline-block` to my image but its still the same. Any other ideas? ):

Comment: @coloroid So it's probably something else interfering. Can you provide a live demo of this?! If your page is online or something, if not you might create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and keep pasting code until you'ere able to reproduce the issue.